# Updated Php version from 5.4 to 7.2 and getting "PHP installation missing the MySQL extension needed by Wordpress"

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to wordpress and I wanted to add a custom plugin which required php version 5.6 or higher.

In my cPnael -> MultiPHP Manager, there were options to upgrade version to 7.0, 7.1, 7.3, 7.4.

I upgraded it to 7.2 but now my wordpress site gives error like

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which
> is required by WordPress.

Here is my website : [Website Link](http://www.sparcopaints.com/)

I have searched for solutions, some suggest that I upgrade my wordpress version but only way to do that is manually and still no guarantee that it will work than.

Please help if there is any solution to this.

Thanks

Comment: I'd try a different PHP version. It looks like your host's 7.2 doesn't have MySQL support, so you'll either have to get them to fix that or find another version that does have MySQL support.

Comment: Or if you are on a really old WordPress and want to try upgrading I'd switch back to 5.6 temporarily.

Comment: I have tried all the options from 7.1 to 7.4 but none of them work.
check this https://ibb.co/3WLkjhx

Comment: WordPress 4.5 added support for mysqlnd, so unless you're upgrading from something before that then the problem is with PHP not WordPress. So you'll have to talk to your host to get them to fix this for you.